# PHP Error - Object of class could not be converted to String

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting an error while coding an articles system. I want to echo the latest article. If there's an easier way to do this, please let me know.
Here's the error:

> **Catchable fatal error:** Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in **/public_html/cms/articles.php** on line 5

And here's my code (from articles.php):

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';
$getmax = "SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$max = mysqli_query($conn, $getmax);
$max = (string)$max;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id=$max";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $articleOneTitle = $row["title"];
    $articleOneDesc = $row["description"];
    $articleOneContent = $row["content"];
}
} else {
echo "Sorry! - No articles are currently available, please check back later.";
}
echo $max;
?>
```

Comment: `$max = (string)$max;` does not compute. Please read up on how to properly process the results from `mysqli_query `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mysqli_query returns a mysqli_result object; you cannot cast this directly to a string.  It should look more like this.

```
$getmax = "SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY id LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $getmax);
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$max = (string)$row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 5, you're typecasting the results from your `mysql_query` call to a string. PHP doesn't like that and is trhrowing an error. The [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function will return `false` on failure, or a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) on success.